# Force Viewdidload on Poptorootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

Is there a way to force `viewdidload` on `poptorootviewcontroller`?

I've got an app in which in `appdelegate` I create a `NavigationController` and in the `RootViewController` there's an animation which calls, through `locationdidupdate` delegate method, many requests to server and then, it pushes another `viewcontroller` and then the app works normally.

The problem is that during the app there could be the possibility to `poptorootviewcontroller`, but if I do it, it doesn't start anything, starting from the animation and going on with the requests, so the app doesn't work properly.

**My question is:**

How can I force `viewdidload` through the command `poptorootviewcontroller`?

I tried with `viewwillappear`, but the flow doesn't work properly.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with viewDidAppear?

Comment: Can I totally replace viewdidload with viewdidappear?

Comment: Yes, just remember to call super. [super viewDidAppear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NotificationCenter`. Ugly way, but task has to be done :)

Have this at the place when you want viewdidload to load again...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ContactListDisappeared" object:self];
```

in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, have

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doTheTaskHere:) name:@"ContactListDisappeared" object:nil];
```

Set action for this...

```
- (void)doTheTaskHere:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // call view did load again... 
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Today only I wanted something like this and I achieved this way.

Comment: I spent 3-4 hours to get this done... you are lucky to get in 5 mins :D :P

Comment: thank you so much! :) maybe I'll help you with some code in the future :P